# sharing code across several Wordpress plugins

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

Just wondering about best practices around shared code between WordPress plugins.

I'm thinking of creating a core plugin that has all of the shared setup and
functions used in the other plugins.

I realize I could probably combine all of the plugins into one big one,
but prefer separate, smaller plugins for agility.

So, how do i include common code across several WordPress plugins?

Thanks

Comment: Show us what you have tried/what research you have done on your own?

Answer (score 2):

All active wordpress plugins run all of the time, so any defines or functions you declare in one plugin will be available in the next. (Edit: As long as they're declared publicly that is)

The problem with what you're suggesting is that you'll have plugins that're explicitly dependent on other plugins so what you're doing is effectively having one big plugin but split across three.

It would be better practice to have one plugin where you have several php files within it that're included in the main php file for that plugin. These can even be in different folders within the main plugin folder if it keeps it easier to organise for you. This way you can split your code out to relevant classes/files etc to keep it neat/maintainable but you're not making plugins that can't be used on their own.